# Why does Expression.TryFault() always fail to Expression.Lambda<>().Compile() in netfx?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-expressions

Given the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(Expression.TryFault(Expression.Constant("hi"), Expression.Constant("alternative"))).Compile()());
```

I am targeting net462 ([repro project here](https://github.com/binki/ExpressionTryFaultInvalidEmit)).

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The requested operation is invalid for DynamicMethod.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.BeginFaultBlock()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.EmitTryExpression(Expression expr)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.EmitExpression(Expression node, CompilationFlags flags)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.EmitLambdaBody(CompilerScope parent, Boolean inlined, CompilationFlags flags)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
```

Why isn’t this emission supported?

I know that my example here is not a good example of when one would want to use [`Expression.TryFault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.tryfault?view=netframework-4.6.2). However, the semantics fit exactly what I want in a certain scenario (running some code only if an exception is thrown by a particular expression without actually catching the original exception (I am actually trying to generate a more specific exception by rerunning parts of the original expression in a bunch of try/catch with the idea that the exception case will be exceptional and rarely run)).

Why does netfx throw here? I thought that even though C# doesn’t support fault blocks, netfx did. What is DynamicMethod and why is it special? Is there any suggestion for a way to express these semantics without encountering this error?

Comment: _Why isn’t X supported?_ is off topic here

Comment: Can you write `try{ "value" }catch(Exception e){ "other value" }` in C#? Exception handling can't be used like a conditional `?:` operator. You need to emit statements, not expressions. In other words the stack offset must be zero.

Comment: Well you might be able to use try / catch that way. But you can't use try / fault that way.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You can do a lot of things in expressions which you can’t do in C#. In expressions, blocks evaluate to a value.

Comment: @stuartd It works fine in netcore which, IIRC, implements `Expression.Lambda<>.Compile()` using reflection. Also, the error is at a different layer—I had gotten past all of the expression validation errors and now the IL emission layer is doing something. This sort of issue feels a lot like getting [`BadImageFormatException`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-/736469) which shouldn’t happen/indicates a bug or quirk in the framework for which I need advice for workarounds or just general information on what I might be doing oddly or wrong to trigger this behavior.

Comment: I had a look at the source for `LambdaCompiler.EmitTryExpression` and try / catch values emit store / load to a local variable, but finally / fault only support void. Which might explain your error.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman But the framework itself uses try/fault: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1217609 . You can see it shown more clearly in the IL in the `MoveNext` at [sharplap](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANnAJiA1AHwAIBMAjALABQeADAAR5EAsA3OeQOYCmCAmgBQCUzMuQCSAESgBnAA4B7CRGAp21DggAa/AN7lqu2gHZqMAK4oUggL4sKRAMwAeOpQB8Kzrz7VtZPbRoA3CAAnagAvagBeN3V+QV8AMxkQnkCQqEjqSkZqKHtqAmyoLCxPOiIDagASACJNKAtqyyA=)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Ah, interesting. I will check that out.